# How to transform an image into a panning video?

Tags: image-processing, video

NASA released a panorama image of Mars taken by *the Perseverance Navcams 360-Degree Panorama Camera* on February 22, 2021.

I would like to have that image as an animated background for my Zoom meetings, for that I would like to scan the panorama over a nice path.

Question:

**How to transform an image into a video panning over the large picture?**

Accepted formats are MP4 and MOV.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are other solutions that do not require generating all the frames in advance. Using the same path as a previous solution, you could use [`AnimationVideo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnimationVideo.html) (Experimental V12.3) which can be parallelized:

```
pathfunct[t_] := {1 Sin[t], -0.7 + 0.15 Cos[t]}

imagesize = {800, 600};
Parallelize@
 AnimationVideo[
  ImageCrop[panimg, imagesize, pathfunct[t]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  DefaultDuration -> 10, FrameRate -> 60]
```

Or if the panning can be described by a list of positions you can use [`TourVideo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TourVideo.html) (V13):

```
TourVideo[panimg, {<|"Position" -> Scaled[{.2, .5}], 
   "Width" -> 500|>, <|"Position" -> Scaled[{.8, .5}], 
   "Width" -> 1000|>}]
```

Answer (score 4):

*This answer was rendered obsolete by the new functions [`AnimationVideo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnimationVideo.html)(Experimental V12.3) and [`TourVideo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TourVideo.html) (V13.0), which were not available to me at the time of posting this solution. See the answer by @carlog*

---

The following defines the URL where the image is located, imports it and checks its size

```
panimg = With[
   {
    imgurl = 
     "https://mars.nasa.gov/system/resources/deepzooms/25622_1_-_\
PIA24422_-_Navcam_360_-_Maki_7_Navcam_360_08_N_LRGB_0002_RAS_0010052_\
CYL_S_UNCORCLJ01-stretched-v2.png"
    }
   , Import[imgurl]
   ];
ImageDimensions[panimg]
```

A reasonable function to pan the image is an oval

```
pathfunct[t_] := {1 Sin[t], -0.7 + 0.15 Cos[t]}
```

We select the region preview the video using [`ImageCrop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCrop.html) and preview the video using [`Animate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html)

```
With[
 {
  imagesize = {800, 600}
  },
 Animate[
  ImageCrop[panimg, imagesize, pathfunct[t]]
  , {t, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/2048}
  , AppearanceElements -> All
  , DisplayAllSteps -> True
  , AnimationRate -> 60
  ]
 ]
```

Finally, we create a list of frames using [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) and [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html)

```
frames =
  With[
   {
    imagesize = {800, 600}
    },
   Table[
    ImageCrop[panimg, imagesize, pathfunct[t]]
    , {t, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/2048}
    ]
   ];

Export[
 "Mars-Panorama.MP4"
 , frames
 , AppearanceElements -> All
 , DisplayAllSteps -> True
 , AnimationRate -> 60
 ]
```

The new file can be used as background in Zoom.

[image]